# Custom themes for Slate API documentation?

Tags: documentation, api-documentation

#### Problem Statement:

I am currently using [Slate](https://github.com/slatedocs/slate) to write API documentation and I have a need of changing the theme.

The default theme looks like this:

[image: Default Picture]

Whereas, I wanted to make it something like this:

[image: Wanted picture]

Source: https://dashboard.clearbit.com/docs

and they are using slate as well.

Or something like this would do too : https://www.twilio.com/docs/usage/api

#### What do I want?

I believe there should be a list of themes that we could apply that would save me from changing a big pile of CSS/SCSS. But, I cannot find it anywhere. There are ways to change the code highlighting section but that is not enough.

Feel free to throw in any suggestions. I would love to try it out.

Thank you !!

Answer (score 0):

I guess you can just download the css styles of one of this pages and try to add or replace the existing ones

[image]

[image]

Comment: I checked it and it won't work out of the box. Question is what kind of tool they are using to generate md.erb/html file from openapi.yaml

Comment: Thank you for the comment. I did not find anything online hence, I ended up changing the CSS manually and it did not take much time as I thought it would.